# Python script hanging

Tags: python, python-3.x, imap

This is the piece of code I am trying to execute. It's hanging after printing 'creating'. Can someone help me how to debug these kind of issues.

```
print('creating')
self.imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(config.imap_server,config.imap_port)
print('imap config done')
r, d = self.imap.login(username, password)
print('login')
assert r == 'OK', 'login failed: %s' % str (r)
print(" > Signed in as %s" % self.username, d)
```

Comment: It looks like it is failing to connect, you can use the timeout parameter to make sure it doesn't hang. https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4_SSL

Comment: If you are hanging on connect, it is likely either your server is offline, or you are being firewalled and your packets are being dropped at some point.

Comment: @big_bad_bison and Max hanks for the comments. I think it is connecting very very slowly. Is there a way I can see some progress? thanks for the replies.